# d3.js: how to use map function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I use `d3.map()` to get `[10, 12]` out of the following array?

```
var mydata = [ 
  { '__data__' : 10 }, 
  {'__data__' : 12 }
];
```

I have been trying this, but it doesn't work:

```
var mymap = d3.map(mydata, function(d) { 
  return d.__data__; 
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't -- `d3.map()` isn't for mapping a function across an array, but a shim for hashes. Briefly, while objects can be used like hashes, there are situations when unexpected behaviour can occur. A new Javascript standard proposes a solution to this, and until it is implemented, `d3.map()` can be used to the same effect.

More information in [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_map).

Comment: any advice on how one does get to  [10,12] as per his example?

Comment: You could simply do `mydata.map(function(d) { return d.__data; })`.

Answer (score 7):

.map() just creates another array, having traversed whatever you gave it and performing a function you defined on each element in the old array and then that becomes the new array.

so if i wanted to perform a single operation on all elements in an array and make a new array out of it, i'd use .map()

for example, i need to see something represented as percentages when the data i'm getting from /proc/loadavg gives me numbers like 0.28, 0.03, 1.0, 0.97, 0.04, etc for every 5-15 min load avg. but i also need the output from running nproc in my calculation, and nproc gives me how many cores over which things are distributed. so i create an array each time /proc/loadavg gives me a new value, and i push each new value onto an array...

This would be your initial data:

```
var data = [0.28,0.03,1.0,0.97,0.04];
var dataSize = 5;
```

This could be the function to use to apply to all indexes in your original data array:

```
   percent = function () {
      return (loadval/(numCores*100));
   }
```

This would be mapping it to a new array with the transformed values:

```
 data = d3.range(dataSize).map(percent);
```