# Getting values of objects with d3

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

Hi I'm just getting into d3. Now I have this array:

```
    var data =
    [
     {name: "Tim", grades: [2.0, 2.2, 1.7]},
     {name: "Mike", grades: [1.7, 1.3, 2.7]},
     {name: "Max", grades: [3.0, 2.0, 2.3]},
     {name: "Peter", grades: [1.5, 2.0, 1.5]}
    ];
```

and I only need all the names in a seperate array. Is there a "d3-way" to do this? I tried with d3.values but couldn't get it to work.

Any help is apreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple javascript is sufficient; d3 doesn't really add any ease to doing this particular task. You'll see `array.map()` often in d3 code as it does the job you are looking for:

```js
var data = [
  {name: "Tim", grades: [2.0, 2.2, 1.7]},
  {name: "Mike", grades: [1.7, 1.3, 2.7]},
  {name: "Max", grades: [3.0, 2.0, 2.3]},
  {name: "Peter", grades: [1.5, 2.0, 1.5]}
];
    
var names = [];

names = data.map(function(d) { return d.name; })
    
console.log(names);
```

Here is a description of the [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) method:

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

If you really want to use d3 to achieve the same effect, you could use d3.map() (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058791/d3-js-how-to-use-map-function) and the [API documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#map_keys)). You can use the `.keys()` method of a d3.map() to get a list of the keys:

```js
var data = [
  {name: "Tim", grades: [2.0, 2.2, 1.7]},
  {name: "Mike", grades: [1.7, 1.3, 2.7]},
  {name: "Max", grades: [3.0, 2.0, 2.3]},
  {name: "Peter", grades: [1.5, 2.0, 1.5]}
];

console.log(d3.map(data, function(d) { return d.name}).keys());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow that was quite easy! Thanks